# Is $x\sum_{n\geq x^{1/k}} \frac{1}{n^k} = O(x^{1/k})$ for $k\geq2$?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

In a textbook, some author wrote this estimation for $k=2$ like it would be trivial, but I do not see why this should be true. And I even wonder if we can generalize this for alle integers $k\geq2$.

Obviously, the sum is always converging (for $k\geq2$), so the "worst" thing possible is
$$x\sum_{n\geq x^{1/k}} \frac{1}{n^k} = O(x)$$
But since we have less summands for bigger $x$, this is probably not the best estimation.
Also for every $x$ and every $k$, each summand is $<1$.
Doing some numerical estimations make it reasonable, that this sum could be $O(x^{1/k})$, but actually I have no idea how to prove this formally or if this is even true.

I'd appreciate any hints on this, not necessarily a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** You can prove by comparison with an improper integral that $$\sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k}=\mathcal O\Big(\frac{1}{m^{k-1}}\Big)$$ for $k>1$.